# Excluding a property from an update in the database using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a put method in my MVC4 Web API like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PutUser(int id, User user)
{
    if(!Modelstate.IsValid)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Modelstate invalid");
    }
    // etc...
}
```

My User model looks like this:

```
public Class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Password {
        set 
        { 
             PasswordHash = HashPassword(value);
        }
    }
    [Required]
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }   
}
```

Now when I call my put method my Modelstate is invalid because my PasswordHash is not set. I don't want to update the password, so naturally, I didn't set it. How do I get my Modelstate to be valid and to not update the password hash field? I tried excluding it with Bind(Exclude) and I tried including it the same way.

Comment: Why it has a `Required` attribute then?

Comment: Because it is required in the database.

Comment: OK, then create a 'UserViewModel' with just what you need in the view excluding the `PasswordHash`. Pass it to the view and when you receive it in the controller validate as you are doing now and then map the 'ViewModel' to the actual `Entity` in your case `User`. Save it and you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a ViewModel and AutoMapper.

ViewModel:

```
public Class UserViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Put method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PutUser(UserViewModel user)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<UserViewModel, User>();
    User user = db.Get(user.ID);
    Mapper.Map(user, oldUser);

    if(!Modelstate.IsValid)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Modelstate invalid");
    }
    // etc...
}
```

You can install AutoMapper using NuGet.

Comment: Mapper.CreateMap should only be done once, for example in the Global.asax